# O que é a numeração ao lado dos comandos Unix?

Tags: unix, comandos

Muitas vezes vejo descrições de comando como esta:

> Like which(1) unix command. Find the first instance of an executable in the PATH. <sub>[[Fonte]](https://github.com/npm/node-which)</sub>

Ou esta:

> A cat(1) clone with wings. <sub>[[Fonte]](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat)</sub>

O que são esses números entre parênteses que geralmente vêm após o nome de algum comando Unix? Tem algo a ver com a versão dos comandos?

Comment: É a "seção" do comando.

Comment: Sem tempo pra escrever uma resposta agora, mas basicamente: https://superuser.com/q/297702 e https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3586

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O número entre parênteses se refere à **seção** da palavra chave/comando pesquisado.

Como o manual é dividido em várias partes (comandos do usuário, chamadas de sistema, funções da biblioteca C, dispositivos, formatos de arquivo e vários outros tópicos), há a necessidade de um mecanismo de desambiguação.

Por padrão, quando você não especifica a seção, se refere à seção 1 (salvo alguma configuração de sistema determinando outro _default).

Isto se encontra no "manual do manual", e ele estando instalado, pode ser acessado com:

```
man man
```

Se fossemos especificar a seção (nao precisamos, pois comando é opção default) ficaria:

```
man 1 man
```

A parte relevante do manual é esta:

> ```
> MANUAL SECTIONS
> The standard sections of the manual include:
>
> 1      User Commands
> 2      System Calls
> 3      C Library Functions
> 4      Devices and Special Files
> 5      File Formats and Conventions
> 6      Games et. al.
> 7      Miscellanea
> 8      System Administration tools and Daemons
> ```

Note que esta lista pode ser estendida pelos autores de cada distribuição.

Se preferir, pode consultar esta versão online:

> https://linux.die.net/man/1/man

Note que, mesmo na versão online, há o número da seção antes do tópico.

Exemplo de desambiguação:

> https://linux.die.net/man/1/printf

> https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

Que, em linha de comando seria:

```
man 1 printf
man 3 printf
```

Neste caso note que o primeiro é o comando do *shell*, e o segundo é da função C da biblioteca.